# How to restage app instance in PCF without restaging App

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

Recently ran into a problem and for troubleshooting the issue I was just trying to find a way to `restage` one particular `instance` of app but couldn't find anything in document.

I do see there is a [cf command](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/restart-app-instance.html) for restarting particular instance based on index

```
cf restart-app-instance APP_NAME INDEX
```

Is there any `command/plugin` that I can use to `restage` individual `instance` of app in `PCF`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot restage an app instance, only an application. Keep in mind that you only need to restage when you need the buildpack to run, like if the buildpack has been updated and installs newer versions of software or if you specifically adjust configuration for the buildpack. In other cases, a restart is usually sufficient, like if you adjust environment variables or a service binding which are just read by your app.

If you need to adjust config or make changes to your application, that requires a `cf push` because that is the only way to get new files into your application.